# Cant implement View OnClickListener or ToolTipView.OnToolTipViewClickedListener

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use supertooltips and i cant get it work, i want to add tip to a text view,I need to implement the View.OnClickListener  and ToolTipView.OnToolTipViewClickedListener right? and when i try to implement them i get error : *Class 'PlaceholderFragment' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onClick(View)' in 'OnClickListener'*. I'm new to java and this site was very helpful for me, this is the fragment

```
 public  class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment
   implements View.OnClickListener , ToolTipView.OnToolTipViewClickedListener{
```

and `(this)` in the last line below have error : *'setOnToolTipViewClickedListener(com.nhaarman.supertooltips.ToolTipView.OnToolTipViewClickedListener)' in 'com.nhaarman.supertooltips.ToolTipView' cannot be applied to '(com.mcivisoft.rcbeam.PlaceholderFragment)'*, I think this error will fix after implement is correct

```
 ToolTipRelativeLayout toolTipRelativeLayout = (ToolTipRelativeLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_tooltipRelativeLayout);
    ToolTipView myToolTipView;
    ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip()
            .withText("A beautiful View")
            .withColor(Color.RED)
            .withShadow()
            .withAnimationType(null);
    myToolTipView = toolTipRelativeLayout.showToolTipForView(toolTip, rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView25));
    myToolTipView.setOnToolTipViewClickedListener(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

use it without implement ,
for example:

```
 mToolTipView.setOnToolTipViewClickedListener(new ToolTipView.OnToolTipViewClickedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onToolTipViewClicked(ToolTipView toolTipView) {

                //your code

            }
        });
```